# Non-zero index implies index $1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Suppose $G\subset \Bbb C$ is open, $0\notin G$, and some closed curve in $G$ has non-zero index about the origin. Does it follow that some closed curve has index $1$ about the origin?

(To avoid an XY problem: All I really need to know is that if the index is always *even* then it is always $0$.)

Seems clear, but as sometimes happens in topology I have no idea how to prove it.

**My work so far:** Oh gimme a break.

**Context:** [complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624819/holomorphic-square-root-implies-logarithm/2625396#2625396).

Comment: If the curve is not simple, for example $e^{it}$ with $t\in [0,4\pi]$ the answer is not

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo If that curve is contained in $U$ then so is $e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oh yes, i read wrong (that the same curve has index 1)

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I don't understand your comment at all. Possibly you misunderstood the question - the two occurrences of the phrase "some closed curve" do not refer to the same curve.

Comment: This question was asked in various forms many times, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393771/alternative-definition-of-simple-connectedness?noredirect=1&lq=1 (disclaimer: my solution is way too complicated for the problem).

Comment: @MoisheCohen I don't see how that's the same question at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like a sketch of how a solution might go, rather than an actual solution. There may be some insurmountable error within.

You can replace your original path with a polygonal closed path with the same
winding number about $0$. You can also assume that all the edges of this path have different slopes. There will probably be some nontrivial
self-intersections. If so break the path into a "sum" of simple closed
paths. One of these must have nonzero winding number. Now appeal to the
(polygonal) Jordan curve theorem to see that the winding number is this curve is $\pm1$.

Comment: A little informal but seems convincing to me. The fact that any closed polygonal path (with distinct slopes so  self-intersections are just points) is a sum of simply polygonal closed paths seems like a trivial bit of graph theory: Say the verticies of the polygonal path and the self-intersections are vertices of the graph, and define the edges to be the edges. Then evey vertex has even index so the graph is a union of disjoint circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Argue by induction on the number of self intersections, $n$,  of the polygonal path. If $n=0$ then apply the Jordan curve theorem. If $n=k+1$ write the path as the sum of $2$ paths with self intersection numbers $0$ and $m<k+1$.

I have been trying for a long time to find a proof that does not use  some version of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: In the above, m<k+1.  I have been trying  for a long time to find a  proof which does not use some version of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).